# Validation of XML using javax.xml.validation.Validator , generating error

Tags: validation, xml-parsing

I am facing an issue when validating an xml using javax.xml.validation.Validator.validate(source, result) function.

```
BufferedReader sourceXmlReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(m_sourceXmlFile));
ErrorHandler eh = new ValidationErrorHandler();
validator.setErrorHandler(eh);
validator.validate(new StreamSource(sourceXmlReader));
```

It is generating an error 'The element type "Name" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".', in the tag where I have Japanese text in  tag.

Not sure what is the issue, but I checked my systems User.locale and system.locale are Japanese. Also, when my user.locale and system.locale is en_US, it is working fine.
Pointers appreciated.